# Android Progress Dialog problem

Tags: android

I try to use a progress dialog. My code:

//Method to load data wire BT

```
private void dataload() {
    if(D) Log.e(TAG, "++ Data Load Function ++");

    // make discoverable
    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivity(discoverableIntent);

    //Show Progress Dialog
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(BluetoothServer.this, "", "Loading, Please wait...", true);

    //Establish server connection
    mAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
    mAcceptThread.run();

    //End progress dialog
    dialog.dismiss();

    //mAcceptThread.cancel();
}
```

Thats inside the main activity, and AcceptThread is in the same class, but extends Thread as a new class. The problem is, that no progress bar shows up.

Where is the problem, do I have to put the AcceptThread in another Activity?

Another problem is, that I get an ANR if the AcceptThread is called. I should be a problem, that it´s not running in the background, but why?

Hope you can help.

Comment: is dataload() a part of the thread class or activity?

Comment: its part of the activity and the thread class is part of the activity, too.

Comment: whose member function is it though? also if you get an ANR. **ALWAYS** post the Logcat traces on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a thread, call the `start()` method, not `run()`, since `run()` will invoke the method on the current thread, while `start()` will create a new thread and invoke the run method in it. But looking at your code, seems like you need to use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I used AcceptThread extend Thread and overwrite the run method. So i think that should work. its running, but not in the background. where is the difference between start an run?

Comment: ok the progress bar shows up. But you are right, i have to use something like AsyncTask, because if I call the dismiss after the Thread start call it will close the progress bar and the thread is running! I need to have them communicating!